# How to Add, Subtract, Multiply or Divide Values from Multiple ImportRange?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, importrange

I am trying to basically get a percentage value. I can't seem to add the importrange first then divide. This is just basic math, but complicated due to importrange.

`=ArrayFormula({IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ/edit#gid=550941148","Project Overview!H7:I7") + IMPORTRANGE("1d-vM_mrlK9CqmWvq0Hn3dS-u1cR5O5VS3gLCGWFPNLA/edit#gid=1199715092","Project Overview!H7:I7") + IMPORTRANGE("1VlUN6dn0pG_ZGazshBFeqMZjRvZc-ge_4lqz0c1iE-k/edit#gid=1385279360","Project Overview!H7:I7") + IMPORTRANGE("1Oo_s92eD9EnTdqR7Z1T85vOd6sCxyjvZZX1hECJO7Pg/edit#gid=1644171545","Project Overview!H7:I7")} / {IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ/edit#gid=550941148","Project Overview!E7") + IMPORTRANGE("1d-vM_mrlK9CqmWvq0Hn3dS-u1cR5O5VS3gLCGWFPNLA/edit#gid=1199715092","Project Overview!E7") + IMPORTRANGE("1VlUN6dn0pG_ZGazshBFeqMZjRvZc-ge_4lqz0c1iE-k/edit#gid=1385279360","Project Overview!E7") + IMPORTRANGE("1Oo_s92eD9EnTdqR7Z1T85vOd6sCxyjvZZX1hECJO7Pg/edit#gid=1644171545","Project Overview!E7")})`

Answer (score 1):

your formula is valid

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ", "Project Overview!H7:I7") + 
 IMPORTRANGE("1d-vM_mrlK9CqmWvq0Hn3dS-u1cR5O5VS3gLCGWFPNLA", "Project Overview!H7:I7") + 
 IMPORTRANGE("1VlUN6dn0pG_ZGazshBFeqMZjRvZc-ge_4lqz0c1iE-k", "Project Overview!H7:I7") + 
 IMPORTRANGE("1Oo_s92eD9EnTdqR7Z1T85vOd6sCxyjvZZX1hECJO7Pg", "Project Overview!H7:I7")} / {
 IMPORTRANGE("1eDIDiMfE5bIi-hEVtwJ7t2wD7A5zTRSt2mHhoQ_mUrQ", "Project Overview!E7") + 
 IMPORTRANGE("1d-vM_mrlK9CqmWvq0Hn3dS-u1cR5O5VS3gLCGWFPNLA", "Project Overview!E7") + 
 IMPORTRANGE("1VlUN6dn0pG_ZGazshBFeqMZjRvZc-ge_4lqz0c1iE-k", "Project Overview!E7") + 
 IMPORTRANGE("1Oo_s92eD9EnTdqR7Z1T85vOd6sCxyjvZZX1hECJO7Pg", "Project Overview!E7")})
```

but first you need to allow access for every unique importrange one by one, by running just the standalone importrange formula

Comment: it has no error to my code, however, it's not providing the right answer. wrong value is showing.

Comment: well hard to tell what went wrong if I dont have access to those sheets...

Comment: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AHtKxsygTlx-07pCKx5d-L5waZCaK3J-VLez3UFqYhM/edit#gid=1230474943] that's the link where you can see a sample of the info I am trying to get from different sheets

Comment: I can see it but no idea what I am looking at

Comment: For example. Under Vertical "Legal - CSA CUL". There are multiple sheets that has this table. So I am combining their values.